# powershell command output ,but variables should be picked from excel sheet

Tags: arrays, powershell, active-directory

I want to use below command
I want XXXXXXXXXXXXX (object names) should be pulled from excel sheet or txt

```
Get-QADGroupMember xxxxxx-xxxxx | Select -Property Name,Department | Export-Csv C:\ABc.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: save the excel file as a csv file & then use `Import-CSV` to read that in & use it.

Comment: The question is rather plain, and difficult to discern. The command used would be how to grab information and dump it into a csv file. To do the opposite would be quite different. Please refine your question for a better answer.

Comment: I have list of groups ,i want to pull members of groups in csv and hence command looks as above

Ask: I have 2000 groups  hence i would like to create csv instead of substituting each group in above command it will pull from given csv Hence i need how to pull these grops from csv and output shud also be saved in another csv